# v.to.3D failing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d

I'm trying to use [v.to.3D](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.to.3d.html) in QGIS to create lines with proper elevation so I can export it to DXF. However, I'm running in to some issue when using v.to.3D. When googling I have seen others asking the same question, however, the answers given haven't solved the problem.
Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
QGIS version: 3.16.16-Hannover
QGIS code revision: f5778a89
Qt version: 5.15.2
GDAL version: 3.4.1
GEOS version: 3.10.0-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 8.2.1, January 1st, 2022
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : '144039.849500000,144976.283200000,6391050.007200000,6391958.898800000 [EPSG:3007]', 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column' : 'ELEV', 'height' : None, 'input' : 'C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GpZPVW/3f386b52772d4970ab120d02e6176a27/OUTPUT.gpkg', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'type' : [0,1,2,3] }

g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GpZPVW/05d98a4597074cb39593e873256870ec/crs.prj"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\kaj.norberg\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_GpZPVW\3f386b52772d4970ab120d02e6176a27\OUTPUT.gpkg" output="vector_61fa996d0c9b510" --overwrite -o
g.region n=6391958.8988 s=6391050.0072 e=144976.2832 w=144039.8495
v.to.3d input=vector_61fa996d0c9b510 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=ELEV output=output082479dbbf314ea99656e58c3006e4be --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output082479dbbf314ea99656e58c3006e4be" output="C:\Users\kaj.norberg\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_GpZPVW\05684025dee14e818eba8dfc329c1c26\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\kaj.norberg\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_GpZPVW\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GpZPVW/05d98a4597074cb39593e873256870ec/crs.prj"
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\kaj.norberg\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_GpZPVW\3f386b52772d4970ab120d02e6176a27\OUTPUT.gpkg" output="vector_61fa996d0c9b510" --overwrite -o
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>g.region n=6391958.8988 s=6391050.0072 e=144976.2832 w=144039.8495
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>v.to.3d input=vector_61fa996d0c9b510 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=ELEV output=output082479dbbf314ea99656e58c3006e4be --overwrite
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output082479dbbf314ea99656e58c3006e4be" output="C:\Users\kaj.norberg\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_GpZPVW\05684025dee14e818eba8dfc329c1c26\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
C:\Users\kaj.norberg\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\kaj.norberg\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_GpZPVW\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 0.73 seconds
Results:
{'output': 'C:\\Users\\kaj.norberg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_GpZPVW\\05684025dee14e818eba8dfc329c1c26\\output.gpkg'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GpZPVW/05684025dee14e818eba8dfc329c1c26/output.gpkg
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Log Messages Panel

```
2022-02-02T15:47:09     INFO    processInputs end. Commands: ['g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GpZPVW/05d98a4597074cb39593e873256870ec/crs.prj"', 'v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\\Users\\kaj.norberg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_GpZPVW\\3f386b52772d4970ab120d02e6176a27\\OUTPUT.gpkg" output="vector_61fa996d0c9b510" --overwrite -o', 'g.region n=6391958.8988 s=6391050.0072 e=144976.2832 w=144039.8495']
2022-02-02T15:47:09     INFO    processCommands end. Commands: ['g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/kaj.norberg/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GpZPVW/05d98a4597074cb39593e873256870ec/crs.prj"', 'v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\\Users\\kaj.norberg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_GpZPVW\\3f386b52772d4970ab120d02e6176a27\\OUTPUT.gpkg" output="vector_61fa996d0c9b510" --overwrite -o', 'g.region n=6391958.8988 s=6391050.0072 e=144976.2832 w=144039.8495', 'v.to.3d input=vector_61fa996d0c9b510 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=ELEV output=output082479dbbf314ea99656e58c3006e4be --overwrite'
```